# Bamboo build failing after intalling Clover plugin for Grails

Tags: grails, plugins, bamboo

After installing clover plugin my builds have started failing with the following error message:

“Failed to install plugin [clover-3.0.2]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.”

Any Ideas? As far as I can tell its missing hibernate core 3.1.1 GA but i am pretty sure i got that since grails runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an admin clear .ivy2 cache and it worked at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have this kind of mess up. For me it helps to wipe out my `.grails` home directory for the specific project. I think that the download was not completed somehow.

Try to delete `.grails\1.3.7\projects\<PROJECTNAME>\plugins\clover-3.0.2` from your home directory. If this does not help, try to wipe out this plugins folder completely. I guess it will help. Good luck :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't have full access to the build server at this point but I'll see what I can do.